# creating chrome extension to change colour of each word

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, colors

So as the title suggests I've been working on a chrome extension to change the colour of each word in a website (to help with my ADHD reading)

The code I have runs without errors but doesn't seem to do anything. The parts I've commented out is when i was trying to split each paragraph word to word but i gave up on that a bit to temporarily simplify

```
var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var words = paragraph; //.innerHTML.split(" ");
var colours = ["red", "purple", "blue"];
var spans = [];

for(var i = 0; i<words; i++){
    var colour = colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)]
    var span = "<span style='color:" + colour + ";'>" + words[i] + "</span>"
    
    spans.push(span);
}

//paragraph.innerHTML = spans.join(" ");
words.innerHTML = spans.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

- `getElementsByTagName()` returns **collection** of elements (you have to iterate over it)
- without `.split()` you will get whole content instead of words
- Whole `innerHtml()` and `split()` solution probably won't work with complex HTML

I would like to suggest you different approach. I would find every word with space with regular expression in whole document (or element) and wrap it in `span` with specific class and style it with CSS. Something like this:

```js
const root = document.querySelector('p');
root.innerHTML = root.innerHTML.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, '$1<span class="word">$2</span>');
```

```css
.word:nth-child(1n-1) {
  color: green;
}
.word:nth-child(2n-1) {
  color: red;
}
.word:nth-child(3n-1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
 some words some words
 some words some words
 some words some words
</p>
```

---

If you want random colors, you can change second parameter of `replace` with function which is being called every iteration. Something like this:

```js
const root = document.querySelector('p');
const colors = ["red", "purple", "blue"];
root.innerHTML = root.innerHTML.replace(
  /(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, 
  (match) => {
    const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    return ` <span style="color: ${color}">${match}</span>`
  }
);
```

```html
<p>
 some words some words
 some words some words
 some words some words
</p>
```

Comment: thanks, however this only seems to work for the first paragraph and doesn't do anything for the paragraphs coming afterwards?

Comment: @charlie Yeah that's because there is selector `document.querySelector('p');` which selects only one `<p>`. Select whatever you want. For example `<body>` or select all `p` with `querySelectorAll('p')` and iterate over it with `.forEach()`.